# On c# the mousehover on a picturebox appear to do nothing.Do i need some kind of eventhandler?

Tags: c#, picturebox, mousehover, eventhandler

I am trying to create a MouseHover event for a pictureBox, but I have had no luck so far:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.ktz00h07;
  label1.Text = "hover";
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.ktz00h07;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = ArgyroCinema.Properties.Resources.ktz00h07;
}
```

What is going on here? MouseClick works correctly, maybe I have to add something on `Form1.Designer.cs` ?

Comment: Please define "not working". You don't have the event binding code here. Without it, the handlers won't be fired.

Comment: how i can add event binding code? i dont know what this is

Comment: In your constructor you should have something like `pictureBox1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseHover);` Can you check for a similar line there (or elsewhere) and let us know?

Comment: Regarding your edit, please show us relevant `Form1.Designer.cs` parts, i.e. where `pictureBox1` is referenced. Most likely event binding code is missing there. You can use `Find All References`, or look inside `InitializeComponent` or your form constructor.

Comment: In other words, if you know how `pictureBox1_Click` is being wired up, then there should also be a similar construction for `pictureBox1_MouseHover`.  If not, then it will never fire.  If there is, then the event is likely being consumed higher up the food chain (the `Parent` control of the PictureBox, perhaps?).

Comment: ok i have add this.pictureBox1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseHover); and now it is working, thanx. but i have to stay over the image for 1-2 seconds in order to work, if someone hover the mouse fast doesnt work, do you know why?

Comment: @user2619988: How big is the image? 1-2 seconds sounds like too much, but it certainly won't register if you briefly hover over your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i had to add this line on the constructor:
this.pictureBox1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseHover); 
although i will use mouseenter, its faster